# Delphi 2009 MS Build headaches

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2009

does anyone know of any good description of delphi's build system?  (i know it's using MS Build.)  i'm using delphi 2009.

i wanted to set up a variation of the Debug build configuration that (often) has different defines (d2009 seems to call them "preprocessor symbols").

the problem i'm having is that--even though i turned off "inherit" for "Base" and "Debug"--have only very limited control.  for example, i can't get rid of FastMM_.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{D7FE7347-8E2C-438C-A275-38B8DA9244B0}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectVersion>12.0</ProjectVersion>
        <MainSource>oca.dpr</MainSource>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
        <DCC_DCCCompiler>DCC32</DCC_DCCCompiler>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <DCC_StringChecks>off</DCC_StringChecks>
        <DCC_MinimumEnumSize>4</DCC_MinimumEnumSize>
        <DCC_RangeChecking>true</DCC_RangeChecking>
        <DCC_IntegerOverflowCheck>true</DCC_IntegerOverflowCheck>
        <DCC_UNIT_PLATFORM>false</DCC_UNIT_PLATFORM>
        <DCC_SYMBOL_PLATFORM>false</DCC_SYMBOL_PLATFORM>
        <DCC_DcuOutput>.\dcu</DCC_DcuOutput>
        <DCC_UnitSearchPath>C:\Prj\Lib\AutoQADocking\Delphi2009.Win32\Lib;$(BDS)\Source\DUnit\src;$(DCC_UnitSearchPath)</DCC_UnitSearchPath>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>oca.exe</DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>
        <DCC_ImageBase>00400000</DCC_ImageBase>
        <DCC_UnitAlias>WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE;$(DCC_UnitAlias)</DCC_UnitAlias>
        <DCC_Platform>x86</DCC_Platform>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_PentiumSafeDivide>true</DCC_PentiumSafeDivide>
        <DCC_Optimize>true</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_IntegerOverflowCheck>false</DCC_IntegerOverflowCheck>
        <BRCC_Defines>MadExcept;FastMM;$(BRCC_Defines)</BRCC_Defines>
        <DCC_AssertionsAtRuntime>false</DCC_AssertionsAtRuntime>
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>false</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <BRCC_Defines>FastMM</BRCC_Defines>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
        <DCC_MapFile>3</DCC_MapFile>
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;FastMM_;madExcept;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

i even had to edit it today with notepad to get rid of a DCC define that the delphi UI doesn't seem to give access to.  (it said "From Delphi Compiler" for the item i couldn't remove.)

does anyone know a good primer on the use of this feature in delphi?

thank you!

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. Are you asking how to set up a new build configuration, or are you asking for documentation on Delphi's build files? (If your answer is *both*, then please post two separate questions. Edit this one to ask just one question, and then make a new post with your other question.)

Comment: I'm with Rob -- what, exactly are you trying to do?  You should never have to look at the .target file -- the IDE should enable you do to anything you need to do with regard to configurations.

Comment: i'm trying to do very simple things.  all i want is:

"Debug" should have MadExcept, FastMM
"DebugForAQ" should have neither

adding things is easy but getting things from "parents" to go away seems impossible.  i would've thought i could simply turn off "inherit" but that has been no help (it simply puts the values back as soon as focus moves to the next cell).  quite irritating!

the "best" one was the one i couldn't even get out of "Base" because it was from the compiler.  it appears it was dragged in during project migration a long time ago.  have ignored ms build until now.

thank you!